# How to test whether an element already has an assigned color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript using jQuery during assigning the color to an element having `id` as `'ID'` we assign as follows:

```
$('#ID').css({'background-color':'#FF0000'});
```

But how to know whether the element has already been assigned a color?

I need to check whether the element has already been assigned the color red or not. If the color red has been assigned, I need to set some flag in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

get the val

```
var old_css = $('#ID').css('background-color');
```

or using

```
var old = document.getElementById("id").style.backgroundColor;
```

also look at this post

[Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

Like Haim Evgi suggested, you could get the CSS value of the element, but if you try this

```
console.log(jQuery('#someId').css('background-color'));
```

on an element without any `background-color` set, you'll get `transparent`.
Now let's say you want to expand your usecase to not only cover `#f00` but a variable color, you could get into trouble.

My first idea, while reading your question was to use CSS classes to identify changes:

CSS

```
/* i assume red indicates an error :) */
.error { background-color: #f00; }
```

JavaScript

```
if(jQuery('#someId').hasClass('error')) {
  /* do something fancy */
}
```

or

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.error'), function(index, value) {
  /* do something with each erroneous element */
});
```

This makes it also slightly more comfortable to set and check changes.

[Edit: a sample snippet]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .error{ background-color: #f00; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('Background #someId: ' + jQuery('#someId').css('background-color')); // transparent
      console.log('Background #someOtherId: ' + jQuery('#someOtherId').css('background-color')); // transparent

      console.log('#someId has error: ' + jQuery('#someId').hasClass('error')); // false
      console.log('#someOtherId has error: ' + jQuery('#someOtherId').hasClass('error')); // false

      jQuery('#someOtherId').addClass('error');

      console.log('#someId has error: ' + jQuery('#someId').hasClass('error')); // false
      console.log('#someOtherId has error: ' + jQuery('#someOtherId').hasClass('error')); // true
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="someId">foo</div>
    <div id="someOtherId">bar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated .error{ background-color: #f00; } in my css file and when Im using if(jQuery('#someId').hasClass('error')) {
alert(jQuery('#someId').hasClass('error'));} in my javascript for an id assigned with red color im getting false in the alert message..

Comment: The element you are testing needs to have the class `error` assigned; could you provide some sample HTML code?

Comment: Never mind, I added a sample snippet. (And corrected a small bug in an above snippet)

Comment: Btw.: There's no need to ask your question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517267/how-to-compare-color-assigned-for-an-element-using-java-script

Answer (score 0):

Use the .attr() function in jquery to get info about an attribute.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Something like

```
$("#ID").attr('style')
```

should be a good start.