# How to compare color assigned for an element using JavaScript

Tags: jquery

In JavaScript using jQuery, how does one test whether the color assigned to an element is red blue, having an `id` as `'ID'`.

The JavaScript statement used to set the color for the element is:

```
$('#ID').css({'background-color':'#FF0000'});
```

Comment: If you've just set the colour then you know what it is, I'm unsure as to why you would want to query this. The page should be dumb and certainly the DOM should not be used to store state through property values. You could add a dummy class, such as "colourBlue" or "colourRed" to your element and then use the existence of that to get the current colour but I still maintain it's not the place to save state.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to check this with the `css` function with only one argument:

```
if ($('#ID').css('background-color') == '#FF0000') {
    // your code
}
```

My preference would be to add a class (`red` or `blue`) and check using `hasClass`:

```
if ($('#ID').hasClass('red')) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would suggest using classes, but if you really want to know the color of something I would use a javascript library to parse the return from .css, like this one: http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/

Here is an example of it in use: http://jsfiddle.net/keegan3d/5SBpk/