# how to find if an element has a color property of white?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using this and it doesn't return anything to me

```
function returnColorValue(that) {
    //that equal to a jq object
    if (that.css("color") == '#ffffff' || that.css("color") == '#fff' || that.css("color") == 'white' || that.css("color") == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || that.css("color") == 'rgba(255, 255, 255)') {
        console.log(that.css("color"));
    } 
}
```

and stranger than that- each browser will use a different method. 
In chrome and ff i found nothing.
I used also rgba and it didn't help me at all...

I cannot compare to any classes ([like was suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517267/how-to-compare-color-assigned-for-an-element-using-java-script)) cause the value of this classes changes between contexts of different pages.

Thanks for all the helpers.

Shlomi.

Comment: if that. *style* .color == ... or if that. *style* .backgroundColor == ...

Comment: FYI - each browser returns the BG color a little differently.  See here for more details: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/e95be0a672c37014

Comment: @Pete: OP's version is valid too, they are using jQuery...

Comment: Thank you @brian. It seems like something that will take me in the right direction. I'll give a chance for that JS function over there...

Comment: That function there needs to take care of rbg conversion. But what I do when I still have to treat rgba and true color's names? It's seems like I need to create a big function to take care of such a simple task that I was hoping JQ will take care for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CSS property for background color is, quite literally, `background-color`. The `color` property refers to the foreground, or text, color.

Comment: For jQuery, you would need `.css('backgroundColor')`

Comment: @Jason: Good point, as I read somewhere that `.css('background-color')` wouldn't work for certain browsers (IE?). But jQuery's docs say it returns the correct value for both. Or is that an oversight on jQuery's part?

Comment: @BoltClock I think that is for the newest v. of jQuery?  I always change the property to remove the hyphen... just in case.

Comment: Sorry guys. I guess I didn't pay attention to the msg before I published it. I did mean to find the Color (text) of the element, not the bg

Comment: I just want to clear my problem again. The color (or bg color) property that jq returns is not consistent. In each browser the value is different. some use rgb, some rgba and some might use the specific color term, like White. Still in my case comparing for all of this values didn't recognized White.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the background color, you want to use the css property `background-color`.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I didn't pay attention to the msg before I published it. I did mean to find the Color (text) of the element, not the background one.